# Delete Spotify Local File

Tags: macos, applescript, spotify

I'm looking for a way to find the local file for a track that's current playing (assuming there is one) and delete it. The Spotify AppleScript dictionary doesn't seem particularly robust. I can get basic information about the current playing track but there doesn't seem to be an obvious way to translate that to a file path. I've also looked into the Spotify API but I feel like I'm barking up the wrong tree there for my use case.

To clarify:

1.) Bad song plays.
2.) Press a key combination.
3.) Check to see if I have a local file for this song.
4.) An AppleScript (or anything really) is fired off that will actually delete the track forever.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I feel like there has to be a way to do this.

Comment: Well, I think I can point you in _a_ direction; this would be the first place I would go: [http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/50691/what-does-spotify-cache-in-storage](see this post). This at least gets you to where the files are stored. I don't have spotify, so I'm just going with how I would start. Then I'd figure out if the streamed music files are easily distinguishable from the other stuff, then see if a 'new' one is easily spotted (pun not intended), and find out what would happen if I just delete it (will spotify freak out, etc.)

Comment: "lsof -p <PID>" lists open files for a PID. May be that can be helpful.

Comment: Hadn't considered the lsof approach. Looks like I can probably get that working. A bit hacky, but I think it'll work. Thanks.